# How do I make my webpage always show visitors the most recent version?

Tags: caching, content-management-system, refresh

I have a website without any sort of cms, and when I go to add new images to it, my viewers and I have to clear our caches before we can see the things I add to the page every single time.  Is there any way i can have the web browser know not to cache the pages in the first place?

`meta=http-equiv pragma=no-cache` does not work, nor do the cache expiration meta tags or any other meta tags.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

the website is at www.nickpassaro.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all 3 of the below together? I was unsure if you had from your question.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

Comment: Will it clear only the cache related to the current website?